# How to break grep -E result

Tags: grep

I have a file

```
gretting: hello the world
gretting: good morning
gretting: good evening
Gbye: goodbye
Gbye: see you
```

i assign a variable

```
var = grep -E -i "greeting"
```

then var equal to 3 line of greeting

```
var = "gretting: hello the world
gretting: good morning
gretting: good evening"
```

how can i break var to each of line and assign it to other variable e.g `temp1`, `temp2`, ..

```
temp1 = "gretting: hello the world
temp2 = "gretting: good morning
temp3 = "gretting: good evening"
```

thank you

Comment: `var = grep -E -i "greeting"` is not valid variable assignment syntax in any shell that I know. What shell (if any) are you using?

Comment: Apart from what Stéphane said about the assignment syntax, you're also showing a command that looks for the string "greeting", but the file and output you show only has "gretting". That also shows that the code you're showing us, is not the code you're running, which means anyone trying to help you doesn't get an accurate picture of what's happening, and that will make it much harder for them to help you.

Comment: Now, "gretting" is likely just a spelling mistake, and that's not an issue in itself. But note that _the computer doesn't understand what you mean if you make mistakes in spelling or syntax_, however minor. The humans reading this might be able to understand you, and mentioning such minor errors might sound like nitpicking. But if you show code with spelling mistakes to us, how can we know you didn't make similar mistakes when giving the code to your computer? As mentioned, that would cause you to get wrong results. So, fix those errors first, and show the code you're actually running.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `-E` is the option to switch from basic regular expression to `E`xtended regular expression syntax in the pattern.

In `gretting`, there's no basic nor extended regular expression operator so `-E` will make no difference, you might as well use `-F` for `F`ixed string.

To assign the first 3 lines to 3 different shell variables, in POSIX-like shells, you could do:

```
readln() for _var; do IFS= read -r "$_var"; done

grep -Fi gretting file | readln temp1 temp2 temp3
```

However note that in several shells including `bash` (by default¹), the right-most part of a pipeline runs in a subshell so those variables will be lost as soon as the pipeline retuns so you'd need to use them in the same pipeline component:

```
grep -Fi gretting file | {
  readln temp1 temp2 temp3
  do-something-with "$temp1" "$temp2" "$temp3"
}
```

Or use the ksh-style:

```
readln temp1 temp2 temp3 < <(grep -Fi gretting file)
```

Or in yash:

```
readln temp1 temp2 temp3 <(grep -Fi gretting file)
```

Where `grep` is run in background and its output is read from a pipe in the current shell.

With the GNU implementation of `grep`, you can pass the `-m3` to tell `grep` to stop looking after the first 3 matches. Without it, `grep` will carry on, but may end up being killed by a SIGPIPE when it outputs extra matches after the pipe becomes broken when `readln` has returned.

---

<sup>¹ `shopt -s lastpipe` in `bash` can avoid that as long as the `monitor` option is not also enabled (as it is when interactive)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -i gretting file
gretting: hello the world
gretting: good morning
gretting: good evening
```

```
$ readarray -d $'\n' -t temp < <(grep -i gretting file)
```

```
$ echo "${temp[0]}"
gretting: hello the world
$ echo "${temp[1]}"
gretting: good morning
$ echo "${temp[2]}"
gretting: good evening
```

or if you want to use an intermediate scalar variable for some reason:

```
$ var=$(grep -i gretting file)
```

```
$ readarray -d $'\n' -t temp <<<"$var"
```

```
$ echo "${temp[0]}"
gretting: hello the world
$ echo "${temp[1]}"
gretting: good morning
$ echo "${temp[2]}"
gretting: good evening
```

Comment: Hello dear Ed this is freeman. Unfortunately, on the StackOverflow, I have been falsely accused and my account has been suspended for 180 days. They have accused me of having multiple accounts and using them to insult others and give myself ratings. I have emailed them several times and protested, but they did not even allow me to defend myself, and they never provided any evidence for their false claims. Do you have any suggestions on what I can do? Thank you.

Comment: @Freeman No, sorry, some of the SO mods can be completely unreasonable, obnoxious, and generally hard to deal with. I've been suspend for complete nonsense in the past too. One time, though, I actually did get an apology from SO staff and a promise they'd train their mods better (after the suspension had ended so it was too late, of course) and that was by contacting them through https://stackoverflow.com/contact. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been a member here for about 14 years, and it is very unfair how they accuse me without any justification and even refuse to apologize. This is what they wrote for me:
We found evidence that you had a second account from which you were voting for yourself. That account also posted offensive content. There was evidence of coordination between your account and theirs.

Comment: The only thing that seems apparent to me is that I once wrote in a comment that I feel upset for the oppressed people of Palestine, and for this reason, they suspended my account. Otherwise, I have never given myself any privileges or insulted anyone. Thank you again, and I hope you succeed. Thank you for taking the time to read.